# How to print the row name if the maximum value is higher compare to the median value of the others

Tags: awk

How can I print the row name if the maximum value is 2 times higher than median value of the rest of the values.

input

```
name    s1  s2  s3
g1  20.17   0.21    0.57
g2  0.19    0.19    94.0
g3  0.15    0.21    0.26
g4  0.09    0.19    0.16
g5  0.019   0.19    0
g7  2.28    0   0
```

output

```
g1  s1  20.17
g2  s3  94.0
g7  s1  2.28
```

Comment: how does `0.28` come in 2 times higher than `0` ?

Comment: oops sorry. corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk 'NR>1{ k=$3*2; f=""; if($2>k) f="s1" OFS $2; else if($4>k) f="s3" OFS $4; 
     if (f!="") print $1,f }' OFS='\t' file
```

The output:

```
g1  s1  20.17
g2  s3  94.0
g7  s1  2.28
```

Comment: Is it possible to apply this code to a big matrix that has many columns. thanks

Comment: @user1883491, hi, it depends on how big is that matrix and what would be the *median value* in it

Comment: I have 10k columns and 1000 rows.

Comment: @user1883491, quite big. I would initiate new question in your place. In that case you need to add an additional operation such as "searching the median field number beforehand"