# How to print the maximum value if it is higher compare to the median value of the others using a big data set

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a dataset that has 100 columns and 100k rows. How can I print the maximum value and its corresponding row and column names, if the maximum value (ex: 20.17 of  g1) is 2 time higher than the median value of the rest (0.21 and 0.57). This should be performed separately for each row name and the median should not be calculated including the maximum number but the rest of the numbers.

FYI: This has been [answered before](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/372721/how-to-print-the-row-name-if-the-maximum-value-is-higher-compare-to-the-median-v/372726?noredirect=1#comment662776_372726) but using a small dataset that has only few columns and rows.

#### sample input

```
name    s1  s2  s3
g1  20.17   0.21    0.57
g2  0.19    0.19    94.0
g3  0.15    0.21    0.26
g4  0.09    0.19    0.16
g5  0.019   0.19    0
g7  2.28    0   0
```

#### sample output

```
g1  s1  20.17
g2  s3  94.0
g7  s1  2.28
```

Comment: Your output doesn't seem to match your description. You say you only want to print the row name but also show a value. Should that be the value which is higher than the median? Should the median be calculated *including* this maximum value? Why are you changing `20.17` to `20`? Is that a typo or do you want some sort of transformation? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: Yes, it's a typo. Sorry for the error.

Comment: No worries, we all make typos. But please [edit] your question and answer the other questions I asked as well.

Comment: Done. Please let me know if that's not clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are tagged as `awk`, hopefully Python will be useful.

#### Code:

```
# !/usr/bin/python
import operator
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'rU') as f:
    header = next(f).split()
    for line in f:
        data = line.split()
        numbers = [float(i) for i in data[1:]]
        max_index, max_value = max(
            enumerate(numbers), key=operator.itemgetter(1))

        del numbers[max_index]
        half = len(numbers) >> 1
        numbers.sort()
        if len(numbers) % 2:
            median = numbers[half]
        else:
            median = sum(numbers[half-1:half+1]) / 2.0

        if max_value > median * 2:
            print('{}\t{}\t{}'.format(
                data[0], header[max_index+1], max_value))
```

#### Results:

```
g1  s1  20.17
g2  s3  94.0
g5  s2  0.19
g7  s1  2.28
```

Comment: thank you very much. How about if I want to use mean instead of median? It will be `sum(numbers/2)` ?

Comment: `mean = sum(numbers) / len(numbers)`

Comment: thanks a lot!. one last thing. How can I change the condition to the maximum value with the next maximum value (20.17 > 0.57) instead of the median of the rest (0.21 and 0.57)?